# Is it possible to do time series forecasting using monte carlo simulation ? If yes , how?

Tags: time-series, monte-carlo

I have gone through some research paper<sup>1</sup> in which forecasting was done using monte carlo simulation.

The paper from Davies *et al*. is one among several papers. I was not able to understand how we can forecast signals after stage 2 (random number generator). Please go through the paper (only monte carlo simulation part is needed) & if possible reply to my query.

---

<sup>1</sup> Davies *et al*. (2014) The Application of Time Series Modelling and Monte Carlo Simulation: Forecasting Volatile Inventory Requirements. [[link](https://file.scirp.org/pdf/AM_2014050513382674.pdf)].

Comment: Hardly anyone will read the whole paper. If you summarize the relevant parts your chances of getting a good answer will increase a lot.

Comment: @Ferdi  Thanks. I just wanted to know how can we generate the desired output variables from the generated random number when doing monte carlo simulation. Monte Carlo method process stages are shown in Table 5. Also a schematic of VBA simulation programme is given in which i'm not able to forecast signals(Stage 3). I'm writing the code in R. If this doesn't help, please let me know, i would summarise it in a different way . Thank You

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible.

In general, computing a (point) forecast involves computing a conditional expectation (the expected value of a process in the future, conditional on information known up to today). Monte Carlo methods are used to approximate expectations, so they may be used for models where the forecast expectation can't be computed analytically.

The paper you link to is a bit confusing: Monte Carlo is a *method* for approximating certain computations, it is not a *model* and as such isn't comparable to other models like ARIMA and exponential smoothing which are mentioned in the paper. The *model* used in the Monte Carlo section appears to be some kind of skew-normal (iid?) process. I'm not sure if that's the exact model or whether it really required Monte Carlo to compute the forecast.

Comment: ....I have been reading another research paper regarding the application of Monte Carlo simulation in forecasting.    <http://www.icoste.org/AACE2008%20Papers/Toronto_est04.pdf>    i have identified the input distribution & generated random variable. How to do the output analysis part ?